# How to build an operating system that is built on top of Ubuntu

Tags: programming

Hey I'd like to build my own operating system (really just the Ubuntu distro as I know the task is difficult) But what I mean by this is I wish to build atop of the Ubuntu operating system as like Apple has done with [OS X building it atop of UNIX](http://www.apple.com/osx/what-is/). I would like to do the same thing with a distribution of Ubuntu Linux except my business would be in control of everything, instead of Canonical Ltd. I'd appreciate and respect your answers on is this possible and how or maybe links to how to go about doing it. This question is different from just an Ubuntu Live CD because I don't want to create an almost entirely different OS then Ubuntu. In fact that is why I say that "I'd like to build my own operating system". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whilst we appreciate that you may not think that this is a duplicate - in many ways, it is too broad to be answerable.  As per the FAQ, questions need to be concise.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian. So therefore, start there. Might be on-topic on [unix & linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)